# Setting xamarin NavigationView menu item font

Tags: c#, xamarin, menu, navigationview

Hi I found out how to set font for Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar but cannot find how to set the typeface for the items.

My menu code looks like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
      android:id="@+id/nav_some_item_one"
      android:title="One" />
    <item
      android:id="@+id/nav_some_item_two"
      android:title="Two" />
  </group>
</menu>
```

My DrawerLayout looks like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:gridSpec="1|8|#0093eeff|K:#ee8700ff:16,l:72,l:16,r|S:#83ee00ff:16,0,l:16,56,l:16,0,r">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        app:menu="@menu/navmenu"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I can get a reference to my individual menu item from MainActivity like this:

```
var navigationView = FindViewById<NavigationView>(Resource.Id.nav_view);
var item = navigationView.Menu.GetItem(1);
```

The reference type is **IMenuItem**. Is it possible to change fonts for these menu items in Xamarin? There are alot of examples using Java but none using C#.